# Retrieving The Files Modified Since a Date Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I've recently had a google drive sync go very wrong on me, and I'm desperately tying to recover previous versions of the files which have been overwritten. Since Google Drive doesn't support rolling the entire drive back to a previous state, I've been using the python wrapper for the API. I have written the following function:

```py
def GetFilesModifiedSince(dt,service):
    recentlyModified = service.files().list(orderBy="modifiedTime desc").execute()
    recentRevisions = {}
    while True:
        for recent in recentlyModified["files"]:
            try:
                recentRevisions[(recent["id"], recent["name"])] = service.revisions().list(fileId=recent["id"]).execute()["revisions"]

                modified = parser.parse(recentRevisions[(recent["id"], recent["name"])][len(recentRevisions[(recent["id"], recent["name"])]) - 1]["modifiedTime"])

                if modified < dt:
                    return recentRevisions
            except Exception as e:
                print(recent["id"], recent["name"])
                print(e)
                pass

        recentlyModified = service.files().list(orderBy="modifiedTime desc",pageToken=recentlyModified["nextPageToken"]).execute()
    return recentRevisions
```

This doesn't appear to return the revisions since the specified dt. I'm using Google Drive API V3.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, about `This doesn't appear to return the revisions since the specified dt.`, can I ask you about the sample input value of `dt` and sample output values of `recentRevisions` you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.